# Google Oauth2 Login

Tags: c#, asp.net, winforms, oauth-2.0

Working in ASP.NET with C# for Windows Forms Applications, I'm looking to provide the login functionality through Google a/c by `Oauth2`. Can any body help me with some sample or links to come out from the problem?

Answer (score 1):

You can find an example here: [/ - google-api-dotnet-client - Google APIs Client Library for .NET - Google Project Hosting](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-dotnet-client/source/browse/?repo=samples#hg/Tasks.ASP.NET.SimpleOAuth2)

Answer (score 1):

```
3 type login with OAuth2.

 private async Task SignInAsync(User user, bool isPersistent)
    {
        AuthenticationManager.SignOut(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);
        var identity = await _userManager.CreateIdentityAsync(user,  DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
AuthenticationManager.SignIn(new AuthenticationProperties() {IsPersistent = isPersistent }, identity);
    }
  [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var user = await _userManager.FindAsync(model.UserName, model.Password);

            //Update : here we need to optimize code , because we have many roles and logins.
            //According to role we need to open Dashboards.

            if (user != null)
            {
                IList<string> roles = await _userManager.GetRolesAsync(user.Id);
                if (roles.Count != 0)
                {
                    this.SessionState.ThemeName = user.ThemeName;
                    this.SessionState.UserId = user.Id;
                    this.SessionState.CustomerId = user.CustomerId.ToString();
                    this.SessionState.UserRole = roles.FirstOrDefault().ToString();
 if (SessionState.UserRole == UserRoleNames.ClinicAdmin || SessionState.UserRole == UserRoleNames.ClinicStaff || SessionState.UserRole == UserRoleNames.Patient)
                    {
                        this.SessionState.SiteId = user.SiteId.ToString();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        this.SessionState.SiteId = null;
                    }


                    await SignInAsync(user, model.RememberMe);
                    return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
                }
                else
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError("", "Your account is not activate ,Please contact administrator");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid username or    password.");
            }
        }
        return this.AjaxableView(model);
    }
 [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> ExternalLoginConfirmation(ExternalLoginConfirmationViewModel model, string returnUrl)
    {
        if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Manage");
        }

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            // Get the information about the user from the external login provider
            var info = await AuthenticationManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync();
            if (info == null)
            {
                return this.AjaxableView("ExternalLoginFailure");
            }
            var user = new User() { UserName = model.UserName };
            var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user);
            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                result = await _userManager.AddLoginAsync(user.Id, info.Login);
                if (result.Succeeded)
                {
                    await SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false);
                    return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
                }
            }
            AddErrors(result);
        }

        ViewBag.ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
        return this.AjaxableView(model);
    }


  // GET: /Account/ExternalLoginCallback
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public async Task<ActionResult> ExternalLoginCallback(string returnUrl)
    {
        var loginInfo = await AuthenticationManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync();
        if (loginInfo == null)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Login");
        }
        var user = await _userManager.FindAsync(loginInfo.Login);
        if (user != null)
        {
            await SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false);
            return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
        }
        else
        {
            ViewBag.ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
            ViewBag.LoginProvider = loginInfo.Login.LoginProvider;
            return this.AjaxableView("ExternalLoginConfirmation", new ExternalLoginConfirmationViewModel { UserName = loginInfo.DefaultUserName });
        }
    }
```